# ADO.NET check if Rollback is possible

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, transactions, rollback

I'm asking myself if it is possible to check if in ADO.NET the current transaction can be rolled back.

The msdn suggests the following implementation:

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally there is the note:
Try/Catch exception handling should always be used when rolling back a transaction. A Rollback generates an InvalidOperationException if the connection is terminated or if the transaction has already been rolled back on the server.

But I can't really believe that a try/catch is the recommended solution to check if a rollback is possible.

I know that in the SQL Server implementation the SQLTransaction objects returns null on the Connection property if the transaction is a "zombie".

But this is quite implementation specific and it only works with SQL Server.

So is there a db-independent way to detect if a transaction can be rolled back?

tia
Martin

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this complexity is handled by using a TransactionScope object in a "using" statement - check it out on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). One caveat is that a TransactionScope will automatically "scale up" to use a distributed transaction when it is deemed necessary - sometimes this is desireable, and other times it isn't, so be careful if you are nesting TransactionScopes.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in non SQL 2005 the transactionscope is promoted to a distributed transaction which is quite an overhead.